# communicating to shift register with ATmega32 without using given SPI pins

Tags: avr, atmega, spi, shift-register

I'm trying to use an ATmega32 to communicate to a MAX7219 chip for multiplexing with an led matrix. However, I do have multiple different devices that I want to communicate with.

I am trying to communicate with the device without actually using the SPI pins provided on the microcontroller. I have made a test project, but nothing is working. At first it seemed there was something wrong with my code. I've been on other forums and people have shown me better code for doing the job, but still I can't seem to get this working. I've checked all my wiring and even connected it to an Arduino and it ran perfectly. So now I'm thinking it has something to do the the ATmega. Do any pins need pull-up or pull-down resistors on them? Or is there maybe something else that is the issue?

[image]

here is just a lazy test. Not even this works, test nor shutdown.
simple test code:

```
//test

#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
DDRB = 0b00000111; // pin 1, 2 and 3 are outputs
/*
//display test
PORTB = 1 << PINB0; // data pin 1 is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin 2 is low
PORTB = 0 << PINB2; // latch pin 3 is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

// next 8 bits

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB2; // latch pin 3 is high

*/

// shutdown
PORTB = 1 << PINB0; // data pin 1 is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin 2 is low
PORTB = 0 << PINB2; // latch pin 3 is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB0; // data pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

// next 8 bits

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB1; // clock pin is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin is low

PORTB = 1 << PINB2; // latch pin 3 is high
```

}

Comment: Why are all the `_delay_ms()`s commented out?

Comment: Oh yes, I was seeing if a delay would help at all. I commented them out when I wasn't using them.

Comment: I suggest you download the Arduino IDE, and take a look at the shiftOut() function to see how they do it.  Your way seems to be a little bit arse about face if you ask me.

Comment: I see. I will look more into that. I had also made a very simple test example until I got the disired bits output. but it still didn't work. like:    PORTB = 1 << PINB0; // data pin 1 is high
PORTB = 0 << PINB1; // clock pin 2 is low
PORTB = 0 << PINB2; // latch pin 3 is low     // ect..

Comment: I've uploaded a simple test that I use. Not even this one works.

Comment: I think your main problem is your understanding of how the PORTB variable works.  Every time you're setting one pin to a state you're turning off all the others.

Comment: OH! Of course I see now.

Comment: Shouldn't correct syntax be PORTB |= 1<<PINB2; ? The or saves the previously set bits in the PORT B register.

Comment: He's realizing that now ;)  PORTB |= 1<<PINB2 to set, and PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB2) to clear.

Comment: Even better yet, just make a nice macro so you don't have to worry with that syntax anymore. `#define setHigh(pin, port) (port |= 1<<pin)` and `#define setLow(pin, port) (port &= ~(1<<pin))`.

Comment: Even better better, use a PIC32 which has xxxSET, xxxCLR and xxxINV registers ;)  LATBSET = 1<<4;

Comment: great advice guys. I will use all of your ideas. Also I would really like to try PIC32. I will do that for my next project. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the port changes should be as follows: PORTB |= 1 << PORTPIN, the or-equals allows the previously set bits to remain unchanged as you toggle new pins. The way you currently have your code written, each time you turn a new pin on or off, you are clearing all the other bits in that register.

Comment: Closer, but that could only ever turn the pin on, and never off.  You need anding with the inverted bitmask for that.